# Use pocketsphinx in qt-android,There was a problem when using the Chinese package

Tags: android, qt, pocketsphinx, qtandroidextras

```
E cmusphinx: FATAL: "fsg_lextree.c", line 718: #phones > 128; increase FSG_PNODE_CTXT_BVSZ and recompile

W libgogojava-sphinx.so: QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Download more recent model and make sure you are using latest cmusphinx

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Mandarin/